# NSPredicate with Multiple Conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to create a NSPredicate with multiple conditions. I've found several solutions, but none of them appear to be working with my method. The best looking one I've found is below.

This is my single predicate method, and it works just fine:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", 
searchText];
filteredBusinesses = [businesses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Here is my edited version with multiple conditions. I'm not sure whats going wrong. Any ideas?

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"businessArea contains[c] %@", 
searchText];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];
filteredBusinesses = [businesses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: I was expecting the ability to type multiple types of information into my searchbardelegage. Instead, its crashing :(

Comment: paste your stacktrace

Comment: If all you're doing is filtering an array, why not use a predicate that's a block?

Comment: @matt, how might I do that?

Comment: @bhargavg, trying to get the stack trace. Thanks!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2]];
```

Comment: ... an `or` predicate is not the same thing as an `and` predicate.

Comment: OP wanted BOTH conditions to apply for an item to be collected.

Answer (score 13):

Addition to @Nikunj's answer, you can also use NSCompoundPredicate for your AND operations like this.

**Obj-C  - AND**

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 1"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2]];
```

**Swift - AND**

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
let predicate:NSPredicate  = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2] )
```

**Swift 3 - AND**

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing looks wrong in the code you posted, which means the error is probably coming from when you evaluate the predicate by filtering the array.

Since the first predicate works, the problem lies with the `businessArea` key path.

Filtering the array would throw an exception if:

1. There's an object in the array that doesn't have a `businessArea` value (as in, it's not an object that has a `-businessArea` method)
2. The object does have a `businessArea` value, but the value is neither an `NSString` nor `nil`

Answer (score 1):

NSCompoundPredicate received a facelift. Just in case someone's looking for a Swift 5+ version:

**AND**

```
let predicatesAND = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[pred1,pred2])
```

**OR**

```
let predicatesOR = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates:[pred1,pred2])
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I suspect you may have a flaw in your two basic predicates. Judging by your object name "businesses", it is a **collection**  i.e `NSArray`, `NSSet` or `NSDictionay` of items. In that case, `"name contains[c] 'mmm'"` has no meaning when evaluated for the whole collection, and should crash. It is missing a collection operator (ANY, ALL, SOME) , e.g. `"ANY name contains[c] 'mmm'"`.

Ah... now I see... you're using the predicate to filter an NSArray, which means the predicate is executed on each item separately. So your predicates are alright.

Now... the simplest way to combine your predicates is at the very format-string level! what's wrong with

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@ AND businessArea contains[c] %@", nameToSearch, areaToSearch];
```

If you insist on doing it the hard way, than building your compound NSPredicate should have worked too - only you employed the same searchText to both conditions, which may caused the predicate to never match.

My advice to you, place a breakpoint on the line evaluating the filtered array and stop just before the filtering, and in the debugger print the predicate description, using the debugger command `po p1` you will see there what is the final form of your predicate, and will be able to determine if you built it correctly.